# How to add a thick resin "clear coat" over a material?

Tags: materials

I am making a wood material for a bar-style countertop and I want to add a ~100% transparent resin-like layer over it. I am modeling this object from a real-life reference and you can clearly see that the reflections, scratches, smudges, and glossiness are present about 1/4" above the wooden itself. This thick clear coat adds depth to the countertop and makes it look very glossy while the wood underneath isn't glossy at all. The only thing I can think of is adding an actual object over the surface and using a glossy and transparent shader, but this is finicky and inconsistent for more complex modeling. Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: use the principled shader in 2.79 and there is a clear coat slider that you can use. *assuming you're using cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the principled shader in 2.79.

Just use the clearcoat slider, even if something is plugged into the normal socket it still does NOT affect it. (There is another socket for clearcoat normal to add bumps (realism)).

This is it turned off:

[image]

This is it turned on:

[image]

I cranked the normal map up way to high, I was just using it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing with the Principled BSDF shader.  Combining a subsurface, a clearcoat, and a roughness map can give some interesting effects.

[image: monkey with clearcoat]

[image: node setup]

If you allow a little of the regular surface to show through, you can give the clearcoat a bit of a tint:

[image: monkey with tinted clearcoat]

[image: tinted clearcoat node setup]