# how to make a wet rock material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, glass

I am making a waterfall/river scene and it will have mist in the air so I want the boulder rocks to look wet (like in the image below). I have tried using the glass shader and glossy shader in multiple setups, but nothing quote looks real (it all just looks like a crumpled metal rock).
It seems like no one here on the forum has had any question like that either. Please help.
[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100745/how-to-add-a-thick-resin-clear-coat-over-a-material if not duplicate (rock vs wood, water vs coating, tomayto tomahto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "glossy" or "glass" shaders, turn the roughness of the diffuse material all the way down.

Hope this solved it!