# How to make a varnish transparent effect?

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, transparency

I'm working for a company and I have to create something in 3D with a varnish effect on it. I can't show you the product but I can show you what I want to do thanks to my business card:

[image: umbreonoctie's business card]

I have a layer of varnish on my "glasses". I want to do that. I tried different things, transparency, alpha, transmission... I just can't get it right. It came up too dark for most of the time. Sure, I tried to just pop the image texture on it again, but it's a lot of work and I have like 15 different products with differents varnishes to put on it.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

P.-S. I'm not a native english. Sorry.

Comment: I think the "Clearcoat" input of the principled BSDF shader can achieve this kind of effect. Note : You can go above 1 by inputting with keyboard instead of sliding the field See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/100745/86891 for instance Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164603/8689

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a mask for the area that is supposed to be glossy:

[image]

[image]

then plug it into the *Roughness* factor of the *Principled BSDF*. Mix it with a bit of noise if you don't want it to be too clean, and use this setup to create bump if necessary:

[image]

it should work:

[image]

Comment: Outch I've never used mask on Blender (still a beginner) but I'll try it, thanks!
Can I create a custom mask from a SVG?

Comment: yes but you need to get a b&w image at the end

Comment: Maybe a little bit of bump, too?

Comment: sure I can add that

Comment: To do a mask you just need the BW image as a texture image, put it into roughness? I didn't find very usefull tutorial for it, sorry if I'm bothering you!

Comment: I'd use the mask on the _Clearcoat_ input of the BSDF instead of the _Roughness_, like @Gorgious suggests in his comment. It's closer to reality when coated with transparent varnish. For evample, a paper card would have its own roughness and bumpiness, it's coated with some varnish which is more glossy than the underlying paper and smoothes out the bumps a little more or less. So use the mask for the clearcoat and give it its own bump (maybe the same as the material, just a little less for smoothening effect, or a different one because the varnish might have some bump due to production etc.

Comment: @ UmbreoNoctie, yes plug the b&w mask into the Roughness value of the BSDF, I've just mixed it with a Noise Texture to make the reflection less clean. Or as suggested by Gorgious and Gordon, try Clearcoat but I don't know how it works.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! And using a mask will be easier as I already have it as a print file. I'm very happy, I could keep my normal paper texture and having the varnish at the same time. Thank you very much for your help! :)